# intersectsNode not working for right half only

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I have two spriteNodes that intersect but at different positions. both sprites are rectangular. I am getting some strange behavior where it only detects an intersection between the nodes if they intersect on the left half of one of the nodes (this node is always the same one and is always a stationary node). So what could cause such a behavior?

I do have some code I can show but it seems pretty straight forward so if anyone thinks it might help just let me know?

Update: it works with a different sprite here is the code for each of them:

```
if (!weldRUHit && [weldRU intersectsNode:[barriers objectAtIndex:i]]) {

     SKSpriteNode *nodeA = (SKSpriteNode*)[barriers objectAtIndex:i];
     SKPhysicsBody *firstBody = nodeA.physicsBody;
     SKSpriteNode *nodeB = weldRU;
     SKPhysicsBody *secondBody = nodeB.physicsBody;

     weldRUHit = YES;
     [self beginIntersectionWithBodyA:firstBody bodyB:secondBody];
}
    if (!weldLDHit && [weldLD intersectsNode:[barriers objectAtIndex:i]]) {

     SKSpriteNode *nodeA = (SKSpriteNode*)[barriers objectAtIndex:i];
     SKPhysicsBody *firstBody = nodeA.physicsBody;
     SKSpriteNode *nodeB = weldLD;
     SKPhysicsBody *secondBody = nodeB.physicsBody;

     weldLDHit = YES;
     [self beginIntersectionWithBodyA:firstBody bodyB:secondBody];
}
```

it works for weldLD but not for weldRU.

Comment: did you change the anchorPoint?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D no anchor points have been changed. also see my update.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem with SKNode's intersectsNode: method.  I think it has to do with a combination of anchor points and of two nodes not being children of the same parent node.  The frame property is used to detect node intersection, and Apple defines the frame property of SKNode as "A rectangle in the **parent’s** coordinate system..."  Thus with different parents you have different coordinate systems.  Either way, my solution is to use this function instead.

```
bool CGRectIntersectsRect (
   CGRect rect1,
   CGRect rect2
);
```

And just make sure you have the correct coordinate system.  Hint: use SKNode's convertPoint:FromNode: method.